# osmdroid - java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: android, android-studio, osmdroid, openstreetmap

I am trying to make use of the osmdroid tool for OpenStreetMaps but I get an error when I include the osmdroid mapview in my mainactivity:

```
The following classes could not be instantiated:
- org.osmdroid.views.MapView (Open Class, Show Exception)
 Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom views to skip code or show sample data when shown in the IDE  Exception Details java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unsupported Service: connectivity
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.android.BridgeContext.getSystemService
at org.osmdroid.tileprovider.modules.NetworkAvailabliltyCheck.<init>(NetworkAvailabliltyCheck.java:21)
at org.osmdroid.tileprovider.MapTileProviderBasic.<init>(MapTileProviderBasic.java:38)   at org.osmdroid.views.MapView.<init>(MapView.java:150)   at org.osmdroid.views.MapView.<init>(MapView.java:179)   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate
```

I am using Android Studio and imported the library from Maven Central. I do not get any build errors.

This is my activity_main.xml file:

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <org.osmdroid.views.MapView
            android:id="@+id/mapview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:clickable="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.asterism.lookaroundyou;

import org.osmdroid.DefaultResourceProxyImpl;
import org.osmdroid.ResourceProxy;
import org.osmdroid.util.GeoPoint;
import org.osmdroid.views.MapView;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    MyItemizedOverlay myItemizedOverlay = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

        Drawable marker=getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.star_big_on);
        int markerWidth = marker.getIntrinsicWidth();
        int markerHeight = marker.getIntrinsicHeight();
        marker.setBounds(0, markerHeight, markerWidth, 0);

        ResourceProxy resourceProxy = new DefaultResourceProxyImpl(getApplicationContext());

        myItemizedOverlay = new MyItemizedOverlay(marker, resourceProxy);
        mapView.getOverlays().add(myItemizedOverlay);

        GeoPoint myPoint1 = new GeoPoint(0*1000000, 0*1000000);
        myItemizedOverlay.addItem(myPoint1, "myPoint1", "myPoint1");
        GeoPoint myPoint2 = new GeoPoint(50*1000000, 50*1000000);
        myItemizedOverlay.addItem(myPoint2, "myPoint2", "myPoint2");

    }

}
```

and the support class, MyItemizedOverlay.

```
package com.asterism.lookaroundyou;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.osmdroid.ResourceProxy;
import org.osmdroid.api.IMapView;
import org.osmdroid.util.GeoPoint;
import org.osmdroid.views.overlay.ItemizedOverlay;
import org.osmdroid.views.overlay.OverlayItem;

import android.graphics.Point;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;

public class MyItemizedOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem> {

    private ArrayList<OverlayItem> overlayItemList = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();

    public MyItemizedOverlay(Drawable pDefaultMarker,
                             ResourceProxy pResourceProxy) {
        super(pDefaultMarker, pResourceProxy);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public void addItem(GeoPoint p, String title, String snippet){
        OverlayItem newItem = new OverlayItem(title, snippet, p);
        overlayItemList.add(newItem);
        populate();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSnapToItem(int arg0, int arg1, Point arg2, IMapView arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    protected OverlayItem createItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return overlayItemList.get(arg0);
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return overlayItemList.size();
    }

}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.asterism.lookaroundyou"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="7"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.asterism.lookaroundyou.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: is this perhaps an Android 6.0 problem?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your error, the problem seems to be

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unsupported Service: connectivity
```

Looking at the OSM [docs](https://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/wiki/HowToUseJar), are you including as a library project or as a jar make sure you have

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

in your AndroidManifest.xml file

Comment: I checked my permissions in AndroidManifest.xml and those were all included. As I used gradle, and a maven repository the jar is included as an external library. I'll include my AndroidManifest.xml file in an edit.